# Как выводить только существующие параметры?

Tags: java

Есть Кот с 1 полем. (конструктор)
Есть Кот с 2 полями. (конструктор)
Есть Кот с 3 полями. (конструктор)

Кот должен уметь выводить полную информацию о себе в консоль, при этом если
какой-то параметр неизвестен ,
то информация об этом параметре не выводится. Как реализовать такой метод ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Как бы грустно это не звучало, но все что вам нужно, это создать классы с полями. Потом в каждом классе нажать комбинацию `Alt+Ins` - выбрать конструктор(он создастся автоматически), после также создать метод `toString`.

Comment: Есть кот у которого есть имя "Вася" , есть кот у которого есть имя "Петя" и цвет "белый", есть кот у которого есть имя "Сережа" цвет "синий" возраст "12лет". Это три кота, созданные по трем конструкторам. Нужно реализовать метод который бы выводил на экран информацию о любом из котов , но при этом если у кота нет возраста , то и строчка о возрасте не выводилась бы.

Comment: Скорее всего нужна рефлексия. С помощью которой надо будет найти все свойства,  и пробежаться по ним циклом, складывая данные в строку.....Если в них дефолтное значение типа - то ничего не делать, если установленное - то конкатенировать к инфе

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну это как из пушки по воробьям, на мой взгляд... А что нельзя переопределить метод toString и в нём проверять значения? Т.е. если имеется значение у поля, то добавлять к выводу, не имеется пропустили. public String toString() { String _out = ""; if(null !=  this.name && !this.name.isBlank()) { _out += this.name; } /* dalee po analogii */ return _out; }

Comment: @XelaNimed можно. а если свойств 15? вот эти ваши if'ы это уж точно не рационально. причём при варианте с рефлексией даже не обязательно знать имена полей....

Comment: @АлексейШиманский IDE, как правило, само может сгенерировать код для переопределения методов equals, toString и др.. Но мы то их знаем, так зачем использовать рефлексию?

Comment: @XelaNimed поздравляю, и что? пожалуйста, можете делать)) в любой компании вас за код в 15  ифов по рукам отхлыстают клавиатурой. А потом ещё и наследники появятся и совсем круто будет. 10 унаследованных классов с 123547 ифами в общей сложности. супер решение

Comment: @АлексейШиманский объясните зачем использовать рефлексию, если мы сами пишем класс? В чём преимущество? Я, конечно, может быть чего-то не понимаю, но так Вы объясните и мне и другим, пожалуйста. Ну и у нас не хлестают, а смотрят на удобочитаемость кода, понимание того, что в нём происходит и время, потраченное на разработку.

Comment: @XelaNimed написано выше... про наследников. очевидный пример.  Соедените теперь наследников и полиморфизм

Comment: Спасибо всем за ответы. Я только учусь долго думаю.

Comment: Нет, рефлексию здесь использовать не надо. Это слишком дорогой инструмент для toString()

Comment: @Nofate зависит. Если у нас иерархия классов и нужно такое для них всех - нужно. Если всё ограничивается вот таким простым синтетическим примером - конечно не нужно

Answer (score 1):

Мульти конструктор в java реализовывается просто перегрузкой метода с разными параметрами.

```
class HelloWorld {
    
    private String name = null;
    private String surname = null;
    private int age = 0;
    
    public HelloWorld(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public HelloWorld(String name, String surname) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
    }
    
    public HelloWorld(String name, String surname, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.age = age;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        String result = name;
        if (surname != null) {
            result += " " + surname;
        }
        if (age != 0) {
            result += " am " + String.valueOf(age) + " years old";
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var hw = new HelloWorld("Eugene");
        System.out.println(hw);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Самый лучший вариант написать класс типа `ToStringHelper` (возможно, моя реализация не самая лучшая, но для идеи сойдет, думаю) ::

```
private static class ToStringHelper {
    private final Map<String, Object> fields;
    private final String className;

    public ToStringHelper(Object target) {
        this.fields = new HashMap<>();
        this.className = target.getClass()
                .getSimpleName();
    }

    public ToStringHelper add(String key, Object value) {
        if (key != null && value != null) {
            fields.put(key, value);
        }

        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder formattedFields = new StringBuilder(32)
                .append(className)
                .append("{");

        String separator = "";
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : fields.entrySet()) {
            formattedFields.append(separator);
            separator = ", ";

            Object value = entry.getValue();
            if (value.getClass().isArray()) {
                Object[] array = {value};
                value = Arrays.deepToString(array);
            }

            formattedFields.append(entry.getKey())
                    .append("=")
                    .append(value);
        }

        return formattedFields.append("}").toString();
    }
}
```

А затем в своих классах использовать очень простую конструкцию ::

```
private static class Cat {
    private final String name;

    private Integer age;
    private Integer weight;

    public Cat(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Cat(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Cat(String name, int age, int weight) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new ToStringHelper(this)
                .add("name", name)
                .add("age", age)
                .add("weight", weight)
                .toString();
    }
}
```

Тест ::

```
    final Cat ivanCat = new Cat("Ivan");
    final Cat sergeyCat = new Cat("Sergey", 12);
    final Cat dmitriyCat = new Cat("Dmitriy", 15, 16);

    System.out.println(ivanCat); // Cat{name=Ivan}
    System.out.println(sergeyCat); // Cat{name=Sergey, age=12}
    System.out.println(dmitriyCat); // Cat{name=Dmitriy, weight=16, age=15}
```

P.S. Не забывайте о том, что простые типы данных (int, double, float и др.) не могут иметь значение null, поэтому и провалидировать вы их особо и не сможете. Например, если не задать значение для поля int в классе, то его значение будет 0, а если использовать обёртки типа Integer, то будет null

Comment: Да, есть нюанс, что вы сами должны писать какие поля туда добавлять, но если Вы не хотите так делать, то делайте через `Reflection`, что я очень не рекомендую.